# Trouble formatting x and y data in gekko's bspline function

Tags: 2d, interpolation, bspline, gekko

I am trying to perform 2D interpolation in GEKKO, and have the x,y, and z data. However, when I input them into the bspline function, I get the error "x_data and y_data must be strictly increasing". How do you calculate the knots and coefficients to define the surface?

I attempted using scipy's interpolate function to create data for flattened meshgrid between the x and y data with the z data and sorted so x increases and y loops through increasing values, but this still results in decreasing y values.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline, I realized the xdata and ydata were the knots of the bspline and the z values were the coefficients. Thus these values can be obtained from scipy.interpolate.bisplrep(xdata,ydata,zdata) which returns a list containing the knots and coefficients to define the surface. These then can be input into the bspline function as m.bspline(xtest,ytest,ztest,tck[0],tck[1],tck[2],data=False)

Comment: You can load in the knots and coefficients when data=False. When data=True, it constructs the knots and coefficients of the bspline for you. Here is an example of using raw data: http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline?action=sourceblock&num=4